# Flutter Web Dio failing to make a simple POST

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dio

Any help would be appreciated!  If can't solve for Dio, what other packages is recommended for Flutter Web to do a POST (I need to be able to add `followRedirect=false` so the basic `http` package is out). Thanks!!

```
var resp = await Dio().post("xyz.com:1001/login", data: {"user": email, "pass" : pwd})
```

Get

```
Error: Sorry, please contact support: DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/js_array.dart 581:7             _get]
packages/dio/src/options.dart 301:29                                                                                       get uri
packages/dio/src/adapters/browser_adapter.dart 30:37                                                                       <fn>
packages/dio/src/adapters/browser_adapter.dart 32:63                                                                       fetch
packages/dio/src/dio.dart 922:46                                                                                           _dispatchRequest
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1612:54                                          runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 152:18                                    handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 704:44                                    handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 733:13                                    _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 539:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 577:7                                     callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>

    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:5331:11)
    at throwError (http://localhost:56880/packages/webcargo_mobile/user/login.dart.lib.js:818:15)
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:38886:58)
    at _FutureListener.catchError.handleError (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:33886:48)
    at handleError (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:34448:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:34474:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:34320:23)
    at _SyncCompleter.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:33803:36)
    at _SyncCompleter.new.completeError (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:33726:29)
    at onError (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:33571:60)
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:38891:58)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleError (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:33884:48)
    at handleError (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:34448:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:34474:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:34312:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:34335:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:39173:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:39179:13)
    at http://localhost:56880/dart_sdk.js:34686:9
```

Comment: FYI this can be done with the http package too. https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseRequest/followRedirects.html

Comment: Thanks Christopher!  How would I use that?  Can I add it to
`http.post(Uri.https("xyz.com:1000" , "login"), body: {"user": email, "pass" : pwd})`?  Or do I need to use `HttpClientRequest`, if the latter I tried that but it caused a different problem see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66339121/cant-post-from-flutter-web-with-httpclient

Comment: Ok see code sample in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66339121/cant-post-from-flutter-web-with-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is missing a scheme eg: `http://`

So try adding a scheme like `http://example.com/login`